# Extract JSON string and cast to decimal

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a decimal value stored as a string in a JSON column:

```
{"path": {"to": {"decimal": "123.45"}}}
```

I can extract the decimal value using the `#>` operator:

```
SELECT foo #> '{path,to,decimal}'
FROM (
    SELECT '{"path": {"to": {"decimal": "123.45"}}}'::json AS foo
) AS footable
```

But the result is a *json* type:

```
"123.45"
```

If I cast it to *numeric*:

```
SELECT (foo #> '{path,to,decimal}')::numeric
FROM (
    SELECT '{"path": {"to": {"decimal": "123.45"}}}'::json AS foo
) AS footable
```

I get the error:

```
cannot cast type json to numeric
```

If I cast it to *text* and then *numeric*:

```
SELECT (foo #> '{path,to,decimal}')::text::numeric
FROM (
    SELECT '{"path": {"to": {"decimal": "123.45"}}}'::json AS foo
) AS footable
```

The *text* string gets quoted which fails to cast to numeric:

```
invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""123.45""
```

What is the proper way to extract a value from a *json* structure, and get the value as a non-*json* type?

Comment: Your JSON is wrong, why don't you insert {"path": {"to": {"decimal": 123.45}}} instead of {"path": {"to": {"decimal": "123.45"}}} (notice the quotes around 123.45)

Comment: The purpose of storing the decimal as a string is so that exact precision is maintained.

Comment: pgAdmin appears to do something funny with the sub select syntax in the FROM causing the second error message you're reporting. I couldn't get that syntax to work either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT (foo #>> '{path,to,decimal}')::numeric
FROM (
    SELECT '{"path": {"to": {"decimal": "123.45"}}}'::json AS foo
) AS footable
```

Notice the [`#>>` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) to retrieve the value as `text` (and avoid any weird implicit casting).

[Here is the SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3996)

Answer (score -1):

A little more modern:

Assuming:

```
{
"additionaldata" :
   {
      "Duration" : "123.44"
   }
}
```

The following select works:

```
select
  (additionaldata ->> 'Duration')::numeric as durationSeconds
from ...
```

Per comment below is a screen shot of the query and results that shows the data format.
[image]

Comment: Your query doesn't match your JSON structure. Why do you then chain cast to *jsonb*, *text*, and finally *numeric*?

Comment: It works when I run it against real data.  The original type is JSON so Postgres doesn't know how to cast that to numeric.  So, first you cast to text.  Postgres can cast a string to numeric.  Notice the quotes around the number in my JSON example.  You're pretty quick to vote down something it appears you didn't understand.

Comment: Did you test your answer? The [*json/jsonb -> text*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) operator returns *json/jsonb*. Casting that to *jsonb*, then *text*, then *numeric* does not work and is the same scenario I presented in my question. Also, Is *additionaldata* a column or a key in the JSON object? Your sample JSON has it as a key, but your query has it as a column.

Comment: Yes I tested it. additionaldata is a property that contains a json object, which in this example as a single Duration property.

Comment: Adding a comment and editing my answer.  I was missing a fundamental part of syntax. '->' castes to a json and '->>' casts to a string.  Postgres is much better at automatically converting strings, than JSON objects.  I now understand @Uyghur's comments in more detail.  Thank you.